# Referencing outer query(UPDATE) column in inner query gives error on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query like the following :

```
UPDATE prog_fatt
SET    fat_prg = (SELECT MAX(VALUE)
                  FROM   (SELECT 0 AS VALUE
                          UNION
                          SELECT fat_prg - 1 AS VALUE) AS T1)
```

that works on SQL Server, but gives :

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'fat_prg' in 'field list'
```

error on MySQL, is there a way to make it works under MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid in MySQL but you don't need it here

```
UPDATE prog_fatt
SET    fat_prg = greatest(fat_prg - 1, 0)
```

should work.